# How to close a STOMP websocket in a spring server

Tags: java, stomp, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I am using spring-websocket and spring-messaging (version 4.2.2.RELEASE) to implement STOMP over websockets with a fully-featured broker (Apache ActiveMQ 5.10.0). 
My clients are meant to SUBSCRIBE to destinations only - that is they should should not be able to SEND messages. Furthermore, I would like to implement a stricter control over what destinations my clients can subscribe to. In either case (that is when a client tries to send a message or subscribe to an invalid destination) I would like to be able to

1. send an appropriate error, and/or
2. close the websocket

Please note that all my destinations are forwarded to ActiveMQ. I thought that I could implement a [ChannelInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/support/ChannelInterceptor.html) on the inbound channel, but looking at the API I cannot figure out how to achieve what I want. Is this possible, and what is the best way to go about validating client requests?
My websocket configuration is below:

```
<websocket:message-broker
    application-destination-prefix="/app">
    <websocket:stomp-endpoint path="/pushchannel"/>
    <websocket:stomp-broker-relay relay-host="localhost"
        relay-port="61613" prefix="/topic"
        heartbeat-receive-interval="300000" heartbeat-send-interval="300000" />
    <websocket:client-inbound-channel>
        <websocket:interceptors>
            <bean class="MyClientMessageInterceptor"/>
        </websocket:interceptors>
    </websocket:client-inbound-channel>
</websocket:message-broker>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write an inbound interceptor and send appropriate error message to the client.

```
public class ClientInboundChannelInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;

@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message message, MessageChannel channel) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
    logger.debug("logging command " + headerAccessor.getCommand());
    try {
          //write your logic here
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new MyCustomException();
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

1) When you throw any exception from `ClientInboundChannelInterceptor`, it will be sent as `ERROR` frame, you don't have to do anything special.

2) I am not sure about closing the connection, but doing something like creating `DISCONNECT` headers and sending it should work(I will try to test this and update the answer).

```
SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = SimpMessageHeaderAccessor.create(SimpMessageType.DISCONNECT);
headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);
headerAccessor.setLeaveMutable(true);

template.convertAndSendToUser(destination,new HashMap<>(),headerAccessor.getMessageHeaders());
```

You have one of the following options to send error while subscribing.

1) Throw exception from `ClientInboundChannelInterceptor`.

2) In your `Handler/Controller`, add `@SubscribeMapping` and return the frame.

```
@SubscribeMapping("your destination")
public ConnectMessage handleSubscriptions(@DestinationVariable String userID, org.springframework.messaging.Message message){
    // this is my custom class
    ConnectMessage frame= new ConnectMessage();
    // write your logic here
    return frame;
}
```

`frame` will be sent directly to client.

Comment: That is a good idea, however, 1) how do you use SimpMessagingTemplate to send a STOMP ERROR frame? and 2) how do you tear-offf/close the websocket?

Comment: @Nenad updated the answer, try the second part and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Kathrik if I throw an exception than I would be giving up the control of the thread and wouldn't be able to do a disconnect. Do you know if there is a way of sending ERROR frame without throwing an exception?

Comment: Looking at your sample and the API it seems that you can send an ERROR frame without throwing an exception: you can use `StompHeaderAccessor.create(StompCommand.ERROR)` and then send it using SimpMessagingTemplate. I will see if that works...

Comment: @Kathrik in 2) of your answer update what do you set as `destination`? My understanding Is that destination is a STOMP destination that the client subscribed to? What should I use as a destination then when sending an ERROR frame for a subscription request that is invalid?